# What if some app change its requirements after I already downloaded it?

Tags: 8.1, store, app-update

I just wonderer what could possible happen in this case:

1. I go to app store
2. I check for an app that just change my lock screen.
3. I check that this app just requires `photos lib` and `data services`.
4. I download and install that app.
5. Now the developer in some way passed *Microsoft certification process* and requires `contacts` too (something that can be use for SPAM for exemple).

So in this case the Windows Phone will prompt me about this or block that update? 
Or it silently updates like every app and gain acess of my contacts?

Please provide source.

Comment: If I recall correctly, you will be prompted (attention required or something like that). However I can not find any external reference confirming it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an app on Windows Phone 8.1  requires an update which requires new permissions (eg. access to contacts), that app will **not** be updated automatically.

The user will have to open the Windows Store app, and manually start the update process, [which will inform them of the new permissions required to use that app](http://winsupersite.com/windows-phone/windows-phone-81-tip-manage-app-updates).

The Google Play store on Android operates in a similar way.